# UIScrollView ImageView with pins on top

Tags: iphone, mapping, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a `UIScrollView` which has a `UIImageView`. I want to show pins on this `imageView`.  When I add pins as subviews of the `ImageView`, everything is great except for when you zoom the scale transform happens on the pins also. I don't want this behavior and want my pins to stay the same.

So I choose to add the Pins to another view which sits on top of the ImageView and is also a subview of the `UIScrollView`. The idea here if you will imagine is to have a layer which hovers over the map and won't scale yet show pins over where I plot them.

The pin when added to the layer view don't cale if the `ImageView` scales. However, the issue then becomes the position of the pins doesn't match the original origin x/y as the `ImageView` has had a scale transform.

Basically this is a custom map of a place with Pins. I am trying to have the Pins float over and not zoom in and out over my ImageView yet remember where I placed them when the zoom happens.

Some code:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView.bounces = YES;
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

imageViewMap = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

imageViewMap.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

viewRect = CGRectMake(0,0,imageViewMap.image.size.width,imageViewMap.image.size.height);

//viewRect = CGRectMake(0,0,2976,3928);

[scrollView addSubview:imageViewMap];

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(viewRect.size.width, viewRect.size.height)];

iconsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewMap.frame];

[scrollView addSubview:iconsView];
```

Code to add Pin later on some event.

```
[iconsView addSubview:pinIcon];
```

I am stuck in trying tp figure out how to to get my pins to hover on the map without moving when the scale happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like your idea of keeping all the pins in a view dedicated to pins (iconsView), but I decided to just add them as subviews of what you called imageViewMap.

Import the QuartzCore.framework file to your project.

Call your view controller MyViewController.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

// and so on

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize imageView;
```

I'll assume you have a pin view or a view controller called DropPinViewController. If you're just using an image, it can be a UIImageView, but my pins have labels, so I used a xib. The pin should point to the bottom center of the xib because we're going to put an anchor point there.

In your viewDidLoad of your MyViewController, add your pin views as subviews of imageView. Add the imageView as a subview to the scrollView. Set the content size of scrollView.

```
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Use these delegate methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{   
    for (UIView *dropPinView in imageView.subviews) {       
    CGRect oldFrame = dropPinView.frame;
    // 0.5 means the anchor is centered on the x axis. 1 means the anchor is at the bottom of the view. If you comment out this line, the pin's center will stay where it is regardless of how much you zoom. I have it so that the bottom of the pin stays fixed. This should help user RomeoF.
   [dropPinView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1)];
    dropPinView.frame = oldFrame;
    // When you zoom in on scrollView, it gets a larger zoom scale value.
    // You transform the pin by scaling it by the inverse of this value.
    dropPinView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/scrollView.zoomScale, 1.0/scrollView.zoomScale);
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: This is so awesome I am kind of sick. I have many other convoluted methods that do this... So simple. I switched to this and it works great.

Comment: Nice trick. You could do a similar thing by having the pins on their own view and scaling their coordinates instead. Wonder if that would be more or less performant.

Answer (score 3):

So one thing I have implemented which hasn't solved my issue but I think it's down the right path is from this article.

[Anchor a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716923/anchor-a-uiview)

I have my view hierarchy as follows.

```
UIScrollView
 - UIImageView (map image)
 - IconsView (layer image to hold icons)
```

The next step I need to solve is to keep my pins added to `IconsView` anchored in the same spot when the `UIImageView` is being zoomed in and out.

I had a for loop that went through all of my pins which are Subviews of `IconsView` and updated their Origin X and Y. This was in the `UIScrollView` delegates's `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

The problem was this technique has horrible performance on the device as when there are a lot of pins on the map there is too much processing that needs to happen.

Comment: You also can use `scrollViewDidZoom()` instead of `scrollViewDidScroll()`.

Answer (score 0):

A few recommendations:

1) You will notice in the Google Maps application that it limits the number of pins that it tries to display by default.  It will only display the results closest the the center point even if there are more possible matches.

2) You could briefly hide the pins during any scroll or pinch action so that the interface remains responsive and redraw them the moment the image view stops moving.

3) If you must display a large number of pins and animate them, you might also look into using CABasicAnimations to animate the pins and the backdrop at the same time, transforming the pins position using the same math that transforms the backdrops scale.  This might smooth the display by spreading animations more smoothly and running them at a fairly low level, but introduces other challenges and limitations.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006672-SW1

Barney

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I find the idea of manually correcting the pin's location not very pretty. Then, I rather draw my pins onto the view returned in the delegate function `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and update the subview (markers) size after zooming has finished.

However, it nags me that this is possible in the Google Maps App, but I can't recreate it.

One more thing: 
Can anyone explain me the behaviour exhibitet when I add subviews to the UIScrollView that are not the 'viewForZoomingInScrollView'..? For example:

```
UIImageView* marker = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myMarkerImage];
[marker setCenter: CGPointMake(250,150)];
[myScrollView addSubview: marker];
```

This seems to work fine for the initial view and when panning. When zooming, those subviews are not resized, which is actually what we are aiming for, but the problem is that the UIView frame origin is moved across the scroll view in some rather weird way. It appears that if one zooms in, the `marker.frame.size.origin` is always moving towards the upper left corner (superview's (0,0)), creating the impression that we are actually zooming out. This is also weird, because the "zoom center" should always be at the center of the screen, no? Well, I don't get it for now.

bump. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Braun. Your code works except for one line that I had to comment out. My project involved having a UIScrollView, then a UIImageView on top that shows a map, then lastly, pins (buttons) that the code positions after sensing a double tap gesture. Your code helped me account for the zoom scale. The limitation though was that when I pinch to zoom, each pin does not "stick" to the specific part of the drawing where I double tapped. I stumbled on the solution when I commented out this line:

//[dropPinView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1)];

I don't have the complete understanding but my code now works! I hope others will benefit from my experience. Thanks David!